# I there a possibility to add navnodes to an existing cloudscribe.web.navigation tree?

Tags: c#, cloudscribe

Hei there.

I am using cloudscribe.web.navigation to build a navigation in an NET6 MVC project (C# backend, JS frontend).

I want to programmatically add new navnodes (or childnodes) to an existing tree (search for plugins in some DI class and add them afterwards).

My navigation.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
   <NavNode key="Home" parentKey="RootNode" controller="Home" action="Index" text="Home" 
   iconCssClass="glyphicon glyphicon-home" isRootNode="true">
     <Children>
       <NavNode key="Statistics" parentKey="RootNode" text="Statistics" iconCssClass="fa fa- 
  bar-chart">
         <Children>
        <!-- here the nodes from c# should be added -->
         </Children>
     </Children>
</NavNode>
```

So, is there a possibility to add new child nodes to the statistic parent node, without manipulating the XML?

Thanks in advanve!